# How to make Activator.CreateInstance threaded

Tags: vb.net, reflection, service

I have some code that runs within a multithreaded class.
Basically i create many threads which contain instance of this class.

Within this class i create an object to either a vb6 or .net dll using reflection, then i call a method within that object.  The object that gets called can be different every time.

But for some reason even through i have multiple threads going when i get to the Activator.CreateInstance it is no longer multithreaded.  Why is that?  How do i fix it?

I want to catch the error returned and put it in a log.

```
            If UCase(pRow("TypeVB6").ToString()) = "TRUE" Then
                classType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ClasstoInstantiate, True)
            Else
                classType = Type.GetType(ClasstoInstantiate, True)
            End If

            Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(classType)
            cError = classType.InvokeMember(MethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public, Nothing, o, New Object() {FilePath, VirtDir})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas for a solution:

1) Verify that the main entry point for your service is decorated with the [MTAThread Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.mtathreadattribute.aspx)

2) Wrap the Activator.CreateInstance call (and possibly the following InvokeMember method) in a [SyncLock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx).

Comment: ill try these out adn get back to you

Comment: synclock didn't change anything

Comment: What is the exact exception that you are receiving?

Comment: i am not recieveing an exception basically it does not move passed the line of code with Activator.CreateINstance until after the other thread finishes.  So there are two different threads and they are seperate all the way till that  line of code then for some reason one thread seems to be waiting on the other.

Comment: It sounds to me like the object you are trying to create is single-threaded. The other possibility is that the object contains something like a synclock or mutex in the startup code to prevent multiple instances from starting simultaneously.

Comment: hmm i have the code for the object im calling in front of me.. It is Apartment Threaded

Comment: its a windows service that calls a bunch of classes

Comment: Synclock did the trick i just had it in the wrong spot has to go around the type declaration